# Cordova - Move iOS photo

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

So, I need a way to move my photos taken with Cordova's Camera API to a persistent storage, so that they don't get deleted when the application closes. Later on, I have to delete them.

I don't have the faintest idea on how to do it, there is few information on the internet and those are outdated. Is there a new, easier way to do this using Cordova plugins? If it isn't, how can I perform it?

Comment: are you doing this " saveToPhotoAlbum: true "?? by default it is set to false.

Comment: { quality : 75,
  destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
  allowEdit : true,
  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  targetWidth: 100,
  targetHeight: 100,
  popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: true};

Comment: I'll try that when I get home, thanks!

Comment: Okay,it doesn't work, even with saveToPhotoAlbum. Image gets deleted when the application exits.